# Android AlertDialog constructor is undefined

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to have a alert dialog show if account info is missing when clicking the check the account.
I get an error in Eclipse where `new AlertDialog.Builder(this)` saying `the constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View OnClickListener(){}) is undefined`.
The code works fine if I add it to the onCreate of the activity.

```
checkButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View Arg0){
            String AccNum = null, Store = null;
            final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(CHECK_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);

            if (settings.contains("Account") == true){
                AccNum = (settings.getString("Account", "default"));
                Store = (settings.getString("Store", "default"));
            }
            if (AccNum.length() < 7) { 
                AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                alert.setTitle("Account Information missing!");
                alert.setMessage("Enter now? ");

                alert.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(CheckOrder.this, GoToSetup.class));
                        }
                });
                alert.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            return;
                        }
                });
                alert.show();   

            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 16):

The error occurs because `this` is the `OnClickListener` that you're creating (in the call to `checkButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){`), not the parent Activity. If your Activity class is `ParentActivity`, try this:

```
AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ParentActivity.this).create();
```

Comment: Thanks, comming from C++ and Delphi there is a learning curve here. Can I create it outside the OnClickListener and call the procedure if I need it?
I tried but the I got another error telling me something about taht I can call outside the class.

Comment: You can create a function in the activity and call that, which would probably solve those issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your class needs to extends Activity, such as

```
public class MyClass extends Activity{
// ... Your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. Try this one.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Please provide some details in your answer. THanks :)